# Why is there no 'vote to reopen'?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, closed-questions

One of my questions was closed and I would like to know how I go about reopening it. There is no 'vote to reopen'.

Comment: That question has no chance to stay open.

Comment: @bigown: Care to elaborate. I don't read minds yet.

Comment: @bigown: The question falls in at least two categories according to the FAQ: design patterns and code golf.

Comment: Off-topic was not the reason for closing. As you stated on question, you have a point with the "question". It can be closed as not constructive either.

Comment: @bigown: Not constructive? How exactly? I was getting pretty good code examples in various languages. I consider that pretty constructive since actual code is being constructed instead of opinions being thrown around which is what a lot of the questions on the front page seem to be. You can make a value judgement if you want but don't pretend the question is not constructive because it offends your sensibilities.

Comment: Had you made it broader and more objective it might have been better. A questions isn't a place to get up on a soapbox. Even the basic phrasing of "this versus that" adds subjectivity.

Comment: @Macneil: It wasn't about getting a soapbox. Everyone always gets religious about their favorite language but no one ever implements anything demonstrating any tenets of their religion. This is programming, an engineering discipline and if you say this bridge can hold 10,000lb then it should be pretty easy to test but this never happens. It would have been even more subjective if I had just asked what people like about their favorite static or dynamic language and to make it more concrete I asked people to give me code demonstrating their points. I guess it was too much for most programmers.

Comment: @Macneil: Also, how would you have made it broader and more objective at the same time. Enlighten me.

Comment: @Macneil: If you want subjective here's a question posted by @bigown: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/1745/7146. That's pretty much as subjective as it gets and yet it has 69 upvotes and 33 favorites. I guess he adds "Please, explain why this is a myth", so it makes it ok but when I ask add code to demonstrate your point all of a sudden I'm not being objective. Code either works or it doesn't and anyone with the right interpreter or compiler can check this condition. I dare you to find a better criterion of objective.

Comment: I would have stated the problem clearly, provided an example, and then requested for a wide range of solutions. The discussion about reddit made it seem more like you wanted to prove a point and use this as a forum. [BTW, I should be a little more clear about my previous statement: subjectivity can be ok. What I meant was that you shouldn't "lead the witness."] That you wanted to "prove" something about "religion" shows that it wasn't really a question, but an ax to grind.

Comment: @davidk01: Please see my comment regarding subjectivity. What I should have said was that you were using it as a platform, not to seek answers.

Comment: @Macneil: So let me get this straight, providing ruby code with two examples at the end and asking people to implement solutions using their favorite programming language is not the same as stating the problem clearly, providing an example, and then requesting solutions. I only provided the information about the article and reddit because I thought people would find it interesting. Instead everyone latched on to that part and completely ignored the coding aspect. Anyway, I liked what people submitted before the question was closed and I'm done since I'm not getting through.

Comment: They way you asked was important, because 2/3rds of the message was more appropriate for a forum and not a Q&A site. I think you should revise your question and try again. The title itself should be revised-- many people probably felt mislead by it, thinking they would see a question asking about language distinctions, and instead finding a post with an agenda. That could probably explain why so many people focused on the non-Q&A part of your question.

Comment: @Macneil: I got enough responses to get a feel for how static languages deal with the problem I had posted. I'm not going to learn anything new by revising the question to solicit more responses since most will be variations of either the Java or C# versions. Thanks for your feedback though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a vote to reopen, but you have to have the required rep to cast it.

It takes 3000 rep for anyone to cast that vote, and 250 rep to vote to reopen your own post.  See the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) for the rep enabling numbers.

Comment: As of now, we're out of beta, so it takes 3K to vote to reopen.

Comment: @David, thanks, edited in.